# rxjs stream emits random value with random time (200ms ... 1500ms), if time smaller then 1000ms emit 'no data' value in that stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, stream, observable, race-condition

I have a next problem: I have a RxJs stream which emits random value every 200-1500ms. I need a solution that: if stream is not emitting value for 1000ms I have to emit instead 'no data' value from that stream. I can create stream which emits those random values with this random range time, lets say streamA$, I can also create streamB$

```
streamB$ = streamB$.pipe(debounceTime(1000), mapTo('no data'));
```

but the problem that now I have to create one stream from those both that emits those random values and if not emitting for 1000ms then emit 'no data' value. Is `race` operator is good for that? I tried but couldn't manage to do that. Maybe creating second streamB$ is also bad approach, because then we have somehow merge those streams into one.

Comment: If I follow correctly, you want to accumulate the values that stream `A$` emits and you want to send all of them when `A$` didn't emit for 1000s, right?

Comment: Not accumulate. I have a stream which emits values with random time [200...1500ms]. I need another stream which has same values with same random time (basically copy of previous stream), but when we don't have value for 1000ms we emit 'no data' value instead.